# What are the differences between Leningrad-1 and Leningrad-2?

Tags: zx-spectrum-clones

From [Planet Sinclair](http://rk.nvg.ntnu.no/sinclair/computers/clones/russian.htm)

> Leningrad-1: A simple and cheap machine, this Spectrum clone acquired widespread popularity. Not very Spectrum-compatible, due to the way the machine was designed.
> Leningrad-2: A much improved version of the above with built-in Kempston joystick compatibility.

Various other sources say that Leningrad-2 was slightly improved, or much improved, depending on who you ask. The above quote I believe is false because Leningrad from 1988 also had a Kempston-compatible joystick.

Either way, I haven't been able to find much information about what the differences actually are. Does anyone here know?

Comment: I presume the details can be found on Russian resources and, obviously, in Russian. I made a note in my notepad - might try to do some search tomorrow.

Comment: Can you read the schematics? Both can be found on this resource: [Leningrad-I](http://speccy.info/Ленинград_(компьютер)), [Leningrad-II](http://speccy.info/w/images/1/1c/Leningrad_2_Schematic.djvu). You'll need a DiVu Viewer.

Comment: @tum_ I can kind of read schematics. but not easily. I will take a look and see what I understand

Answer (score 5):

The second paragraph of [this article](http://micklab.ru/ZX%20Spectrum/Leningrad2.htm) lists the differences of Leningrad-2 from the original Leningrad:

> Из конструктивных отличий от Ленинград следует отметить, что
> изменилась схема сброса кадровых счетчиков, теперь сброс происходил по
> 312 строке, что является стандартом для ZX Spectrum машин.
> Продолжительность сигнала прерывания теперь задается не RC цепочкой, а
> фиксированно по сигналу счетчика строчной развертки. Кроме того введен
> дешифратор для разделения обращения процессора к ПЗУ и ОЗУ. В
> видеоформирователе была заменена связка К555ИР9 и К555ИР16 на три
> микросхемы К555ИР16, в выходном каскаде цвета вместо транзисторов
> используются логические элементы с открытым коллекотором К555ЛН2.
> Также был изменен и магнитофонный интерфейс, вместо компаратора
> К512СА3, узел был собран на микросхеме К561ЛН2. Кроме того на плате
> появились разъемы ОНЦ-КГ-4-5/16Р, которые позволяли обходится без кучи
> проводов, при подключения внешних устройств делая саму плату более
> аккуратной и ремонтопригодной. Но главным нововведением, на мой
> взгляд, является добавление системного разъема, который давал
> возможность подключать внешние устройства, как например контроллер
> дисковода.

I'm providing this auto-translation by [translate.ru](https://www.translate.ru/links/8557af1f) online service, which, with a bit of imagination, does make some sense:

> From the design differences from Leningrad, it should be noted that
> the scheme for resetting the frame counters has changed; now the reset
> takes place on line 312, which is the standard for ZX Spectrum
> machines. The duration of the interrupt signal is now set not by the
> RC filter, but by the horizontal scan counter signal. In addition, a
> decoder is introduced to separate the processor's access to ROM and
> RAM. In the video generator, the bundle K555IR9 and K555IR16 was
> replaced with three microcircuits K555IR16, in the color output stage,
> instead of transistors, logic elements with an open collector K555LN2
> are used. The tape interface was also changed, instead of the
> comparator K512SA3, the node was assembled on the chip K561LN2. In
> addition, ONTs-KG-4-5/16R connectors appeared on the board, which made
> it possible to do without a heap of wires, when connecting external
> devices, making the board itself neater and more repairable. But the
> main innovation, in my opinion, is the addition of a system connector
> that made it possible to connect external devices, such as a disk
> drive controller.

Comment: I touched the machine translation up a bit

Comment: I could not figure this out myself, so I asked the author of the quoted article through the [Contact](http://micklab.ru/contact1.htm) link on his site. Let's see if I get a reply.